Почему не работает вывод значения из QLineEdit.text() в PySide6?
Пытаюсь вывести из переменной balance введенное в QLineEdit значение, но почему-то оно не передается, без ошибки, значение ''. При этом код дальше выполняется и выводит print('balance') для теста.. В чем может быть проблема? Раньше подобные конструкции в PyQT5 работали нормально, в PySide6 что-то пошло не так(
import sys
from pathlib import Path
from PySide6.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow
from PySide6 import QtWidgets
from trade_ByBit_ui import Ui_MainWindow
import json
class App(QMainWindow):
def __init__(self):
    super(App, self).__init__()
    self.ui = Ui_MainWindow()
    self.ui.setupUi(self)

    file = Path('settingBase.json')
    self.create_settings_base(file)

    # self.ui.pushButton_update_on.clicked.connect(self.create_conn)
    self.ui.pushButton_Save_settings.clicked.connect(self.saving_settings(file))

Создание БД настроек
def create_settings_base(self, file):
    if not file.exists():
        file.touch()
        print('ok')

def saving_settings(self, file):
    balance = self.ui.le_Balance.text()
    print(balance)
    print('balance')


Вам надо поменять
self.ui.pushButton_Save_settings.clicked.connect(self.saving_settings(file)

на
self.ui.pushButton_Save_settings.clicked.connect(lambda: self.saving_settings(file))


Спасибо, получилось! а можете объяснить почему так?

В первом варианте функция self.saving_settings(file) вызывается немедленно, когда выполняется эта строка кода. Это означает, что результат выполнения функции будет передан в connect, а не сама функция. По сути, вы не прикрепляете обработчик события к кнопке, а просто вызываете функцию сразу при инициализации.
Во втором варианте используется lambda, чтобы создать анонимную функцию (лямбда-функцию), которая не выполняется сразу. Вместо этого она будет выполнена только в момент нажатия кнопки. Таким образом, self.saving_settings(file) будет вызвана именно тогда, когда кнопка будет нажата.
